# Using Google Apps and Server Email

Tags: email, google-apps, mx-record

**Here's my current setup**

Domain hosted at godaddy.com - I point my dns to dns.he.net nameservers

DNS hosted at dns.he.net - I point my A record to my server IP

Email hotsted on google apps - I point my MX record to Google Apps

Site hosted on apache server with a cpanel type thing.

All of my email accounts are on google apps. We have about 40 emails on there, and we want to keep google apps, it makes our life easier.

**The problem:**

Google Apps only allows 500 sent emails a day via one account (yes you can send 2000 if we upgrade, but that's 40*$5 per month and that's too $$ much for email.

My website keeps hitting the 500 email send limit a day for our sales@mysite.com email. I need to push that one email account to my server and use my server to send the emails from there, since there is no sending limit on that.

**My Question:**

How can I keep google apps for all of my email accounts except one, and how do I forward just that 1 email address to route though my server to send and receive emails?

Comment: Not a direct solution, but I'd highly recommend using an Email Service Provider like SendGrid, Mandrill, or Mailgun for outgoing and automated emails. They're super easy to setup on your domain and all have very reasonable free tiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other email services like SendGrid, Mandrill (Mailchimp), Mailgun, etc. aside, you can use Groups and have a higher limit. See [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6099642?hl=en).

Group provisioning and maintenance can be done with tools like [GAM](http://www.ditoweb.com/dito-gam)